# Rails scaffold parameter non permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I have a Ruby on Rails application with some generated scaffold.
Now, in one of them I need to add a parameter that wasn't planned initially.

The situation is that I have two objects: Block and Keywords. The relationship between them is `has_and_belongs_to_many`. That allows me to have many keywords associated to many blocks and vice versa.
I want to add the option to add some keywords to the object Block during the creation.

I added the following code in the `/views/blocks/_form.html.erb` file:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :keywords %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:keywords, @keywords.order(:name), :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {:multiple => true}) %>
  </div>
```

I added the parameter in the controller as well:

```
def block_params
  params.require(:block).permit(:name, :title, :description, :price, :instagram, :image, :main, :action, :keywords, :block_type_id, :module_keyword_id, :playlist_id)
end
```

Nevertheless I get this message in the log

```
Unpermitted parameter: keywords
```

and the keywords are not added to the block.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When a parameter is an array, you have to permit it as an array with this:

```
def block_params
  params.require(:block).permit(:name, :title, :description, :price, :instagram, :image, :main, :action, :block_type_id, :module_keyword_id, :playlist_id, :keywords, keywords: [])
end
```

note the "keywords: []", also note that I also left the ":keywords" key, that permits the param when you send an empty value too (en case you are removing all keywords for example).

Comment: Hello there! with your code I get this error: .../blocks_controller.rb:92: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ..., keywords: [], :block_type_id, :module_keyword_id, :playlis... ... ^

Comment: My bad, you have to put the "keywords: []" at the end, I'll edit my answer.